# How to disable paste in a textarea or solve the length counting issue?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea element in my HTML document where the user can input text. I have also added a span element to show the maximum allowed number of characters. I am using the following JavaScript code to update the counter as the user types:

This code js

```
span.innerHTML = textarea.value.length;
textarea.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    span.innerHTML = textarea.value.length;
    if (textarea.value.length> 9 || !(event.keyCode>=65 || event.keyCode<=90)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

this code HTML

```html
<body>
    <span>Maximum De Caractere est : <span id="span"></span> </span><br>
    <textarea id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <script src="sc.js"></script>
</body>
```

The code is working as expected, except for one issue. When the user pastes text into the textarea, the length counter does not update correctly. Instead, it shows the length of the text before the paste operation. I want to either disable the paste option in the textarea or fix the length counting issue.

Can someone please suggest a solution or workaround for this problem?

Comment: You can add another `.addEventListener("paste", ....`  which will react on the paste event..

Comment: also, read this: [mre]

Comment: To get the counter to be accurate, use the `keyup` event. To disable paste, use the `paste` event and then `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit your text input to a maximum length then this can be done through the DOM attribute `maxlength`. There is no need for further restrictions like the deactivation of cut and paste events. These restrictions are of course possible, but commented out in my snippet.

```js
const [sp,ta]=["sp","ta"].map(id=>document.getElementById(id)),
      cnt=ev=>sp.textContent=ta.value.length;
ta.addEventListener("input", cnt);cnt();
// "cut,copy,paste,drag,drop".split(",").forEach(ev=>ta.addEventListener(ev,e=>e.preventDefault()));
```

```html
<span>count: <span id="sp"></span> </span> of 10.<br>
<textarea id="ta" cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="10">hello</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

User `keyup` instead of `keydown`. Since data need to process afterthe keypress.

```js
var span = document.getElementById("span");
span.innerHTML = textarea.value.length;
textarea.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    span.innerHTML = textarea.value.length;
    if (textarea.value.length> 9 || !(event.keyCode>=65 || event.keyCode<=90)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<body>
    <span>Maximum De Caractere est : <span id="span"></span> </span><br>
    <textarea id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <script src="sc.js"></script>
</body>
```

## EDIT

1. Make textarea count to be accurate when press any letter it counts until keyup.
2. Add js in textarea to disable *cut*, *copy*, *paste*, *drag*, *drop*, including *selecting all text(Ctrl+A)*

```js
var span = document.getElementById("span");
span.innerHTML = textarea.value.length;
textarea.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
    span.innerHTML = textarea.value.length;
});
```

```html
<span>Maximum De Caractere est : <span id="span"></span> </span><br>
<textarea id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" onCopy="return false" onCut="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false"></textarea>
<script src="sc.js"></script>
```

Comment: The code you provided is not working well

Comment: What part is not working? please specify. Btw, I edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event for a better reflection of when the `<textarea>` value changes. This will ensure the character count is correct not only for pasting, but for when a user highlights multiple characters and deletes them.

```js
span.innerHTML = textarea.value.length;

textarea.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (textarea.value.length> 9 || !(event.keyCode>=65 || event.keyCode<=90)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});

textarea.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
    span.innerHTML = textarea.value.length;
});
```

```html
 <span>Maximum De Caractere est : <span id="span"></span> </span><br>
 <textarea id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: your code does not work well in this case when you type 10 characters the deletion does not work check your code ?

Comment: That is not part of my code, but from the original code from the question. My solution solves the problem of the length counter so that it now updates correctly. The issue of when you type 10 characters the deletion does not work is evident in the original code of the question and is not asked or answered here.

Comment: yes but can you add ?

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS you can add a separate

```
addEventListener("paste", (event) => {});
# or:
onpaste = (event) => {};
```

to capture and react on the `paste` event... which can calculate the new input and if needed remove the last `n` of characters so that it meets your limit.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event

---

You cannot disable the paste, but you ca set the textarea to `readonly` or `disabled` property (as a workaround)..

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the number of characters in a textarea to 10, whether typed or pasted. It sets an event listener to detect changes in the textarea and uses the 'slice' function to limit the input to 10 characters, displaying the current character count in a span element.

```js
    const textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
    const span = document.getElementById("span");

    textarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
        const value = this.value;
        if (value.length > 10) {
            this.value = value.slice(0, 10);
        }
        span.innerHTML = this.value.length;
    });
```

```html
<span>Maximum De Caractere est : <span id="span">0</span> </span><br>
<textarea id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```